# Avoid conflicts when using ThemeProvider

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, styles

I am using two different React applications on the same HTML page. Both are using Material-UI and ThemeProvider components.

But as far as I can see, custom styles from one react app breaks the styling in another react app.

How to prevent this? May I specify different CSS "domains" for apps so they will not conflict?

---

**Update**:

The proposed solution fixed a part of the problem. However, I found one more.

There are tags that have two or more classes assigned, for example,
MuiButtonBase-root MuiListItem-root MuiMenuItem-root...

These classes often have different values for the same properties, for example `.MuiButtonBase-root` has `margin: 0` but it's not a problem in case other styles are applied AFTER the root style. And the standalone React app works well.

The problem becomes when we have TWO React apps on the same page. As a result, the `.MuiButtonBase-root` or the second app resets all the margins that were set by the first application.

My first idea was to change the "Mui**" prefix somehow so the second application will not reset the styles of the first application.

Do you think it's a good idea and how it can be implemented?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, it solved a part of problem - with jssX styles. But I also see another problem... Mui** styles are also conflicting. I've described more in the main question.

Comment: Have you tried [`options.seed`](https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#creategenerateclassname-options-class-name-generator) ?

Comment: @Fraction Hi, createGenerateClassName() is for jss styles. It was a problem, but createGenerateClassName fixed it. Now I have different prefixes for JSS STYLES and it's okay. But the problem now is for Mui* styles. They can not be renamed or can be?

Comment: Okay, I finally got it! What I did: I set up options.seed value of createGenerateClassName() different for both apps and finally this makes all styles UNIQUE. Thanks all for helping me with this.